# WebRTC Streaming between PC and Mobile Client

Tags: p2p, webrtc

I would like to implement peer to peer communication between mobile device (iOS & Android) AND Windows PC, I would like Mobile app will stream camera output to PC(no audio will require), and on PC user will able to capture screenshot from running steam. Below is possibility I am thinking.

**Option 1 :** Develop a Web based application which will run in Google Chrome or Firefox browser on Windows PC, and also will develop mobile client app which will run on Android and iOS devices, and using WebRTC it will steam mobile camera output to website which will be running in PC’s Chrome or Safari browser, and User will able to capture screenshot from running steam and that will be saved on user’s computer. Drawback of this solution is that I have to develop Website so will have not user’s computer file storage, as standalone desktop application is more preferable because desktop application will able to easily access user’s computer file system

**Option 2:**  Develop 3 applications

1. one Standalone desktop application which will have all features which require to access computer’s local file system.
2. Develop a small web site which will have just a single screen, it will use for display mobile camera steam, and user will capture output from that page, will develop a kind of watchdog service in desktop app, which will grab latest captured screen from Chrome or Firefox browser.
3. 3rd app would be mobile client which will be running on mobile which will stream camera output to PC using WebRTC. Drawback of this solution is that this solution would be not real-time, because user have to use two separate interface for Screen capture have to use PC Chrome or Firefox browser, and after screen capture  have to move back to PC application.

My understanding is that It’s not possible to have Server less solution for WebRTC, Signaling server will require, I found some of open source WebRTC servers i.e.  Easyrtc, signalmaster  which I have to use and have to configure in own environment.

As this is my first WebRTC  based project, so would like to know your opinion about Solution which i am thinking, is it right or is there any better way to achieve it.

Thanks
Suresh

Answer (score 1):

Hi suresh  IOS not support WebRTC,But its possible in android

My option is Node-webkit(desktop app using HTML 5,Javascript,css3,Nodejs,NPM)
https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit/wiki

mobile app(intel xdk ) but ios not support WebRTC 
http://xdk-software.intel.com/

Comment: Murugan Thanks for your reply, I will check more about node-webkit. Any suggestion about Signaling server?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Twilio Video to do this.

You can build multi-party video calling into both web and native applications with the SDKs for:

- JavaScript
- iOS
- Android

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video

You will also find the server-side starter apps in various languages you need to get started quickly.

In my preferred language example Python, a small Flask app handles token creation to handle user access for video conversations in `app.py` and the basic WebRTC functions can be found in `quickstart.js`.

*Note: I work for Twilio.*